# TS Lint in Visual Studio Code suddenly indicates wrong lint errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, lint, tslint, linter

I haven't touched VS Code or my computer for 5 weeks (vacation) and now suddenly out of nowhere the TS lint started wildly showing lint errors that are completely incorrect. They aren't even close to being correct and it shows it in files that haven't been changed that has previously had no lint errors. Its basically throwing random errors at me. And if I lint via the terminal it reports no errors.

This has happened several times in VS Code and also in Atom. Don't really know how it got fixed, it just shows up and then vanishes eventually.

Anyone have experienced this or know what it might be?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Extensions and disable eslint, the reload the VScode, then enable eslint again.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZEDx.png)

Comment: Already done that. I have also restarted the entire computer. Didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the entire extension, then installing it again.

Comment: Yup, uninstalled the extension. Restarted VSC. Installed extension. Restarted VSC. Still the same.

Comment: I think the unique solution you still have is to update VScode, otherwise, can you put a screenshot to see how the errors looks like in your editor.

Comment: Had no idea how to do that in the comment, but edited my original question with a screenshot. None of these lints are correct. These files have been fine for a long time and has not been edited.

Comment: I understand now, this not an eslint problem, but typescript problem, I think you should disable typescript built in extension if you're not using it.

Comment: Ah you mean there's some kind of conflict? How do I disable the built in typescript extension?

Comment: It might have worked. Added "typescript.validate.enable": false in my settings file and now it seems to only be using the ts linter extension and not the built in one. I'll try it out a bit more.

Comment: Glad it worked, in general to disable a built in extension, you go to extensions and you search for @builtin then the name of what you looking for.

Comment: So far it hasn't come up since. I think you were spot on correct. Marked this as correct. So, a huge thank you to you! :D

Answer (score 0):

check your file association, sometimes Vscode goes haywire on update.

re-set your file association manually to the correct type then ctrl + shift + p and choose developer: reload window